# Download a row attachment using smart sheet API C#

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

I am referring below link

[link](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/samples/blob/master/c%23/3%20-%20SmartsheetAttachments/SmartsheetAttachments.cs)

and used following lines -

```
     public void downloadAttachment(Attachment attach)
    { 
        SmartsheetRequest getAttachment = new SmartsheetRequest { callURL = "/attachment/" + attach.Id, method = "GET", contentType = "application/json" };
        var jsonGetAttachment = getAttachment.MakeRequest("null");
        getAttachment.DownloadAttachment(jsonGetAttachment["url"], jsonGetAttachment["sizeInKb"], jsonGetAttachment["name"]);
    }
```

to download an attachment.

But the following line

```
        Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

in "MakeRequest" method gives "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.

Solution:-

The below line of code-

```
SmartsheetRequest getAttachment = new SmartsheetRequest { callURL = "/attachment/" + attach.Id, method = "GET", contentType = "application/json" };
```

was changed to below line-

```
SmartsheetRequest getAttachment = new SmartsheetRequest { callURL = "/sheets/" + SheetID + "/attachments/" + attach.Id, method = "GET", contentType = "application/json"};
```